# NRF24L01+ RX Mode and Flush

Tags: stm32, flush, fifo, receiver

I have been trying to write my own code for NRF24L01+. I have a problem and I can not solve it

As a receiver, I use STM32F103C8T6 and as a transmitter I use Arduino Uno.

The problem is related to RX Operation.

As I've mentioned above,

As a receiver, I use STM32F103C8T6 and as a transmitter I use Arduino Uno.

Both sides;

1. Are communicationg through the same address.
2. Have the same CRC Length
3. Do not use Enhanced Mode
4. Have the same address width
5. Have the same payload width
6. have the same communication data rate. (1Mbps)

Here is the algorith I use to get coming data from the transmitter. **By the way, I do not use IRQ Pin.**

1. Set CE high
2. Check RX_DR bit in STATUS register. If a value arrives RX FIFO this bit is set. If so, bring CE low to stop RX operation. (Datasheet says **RX_DR bit is Data Ready RX FIFO interrupt. Asserted when new data arrives RX FIFO**)
3. Use R_RX_Payload command described in the datasheet and assign the data to a variable.
4. Clear RX FIFO
5. Clear RX_DR bit in STATUS register,( write 1)

But it does not work.

```
void RX_Mode()
```

{

```
ChipEnable_high(); // CE=1

//Check RX_DR bit. Wait until a value appears.
while(check)
{
    ReadRegister(REG_STATUS,1);

    if( (reg_data & 0x40) == 0x40 ){check = false;}         
}


ChipEnable_low(); // CE=0

csn_low(); //CSN=0
HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)COMD_R_RX_PAYLOAD, &received_data, 1, 150); // Read the data
csn_high(); // CSN=1

Flush_RX(); //Clear RX FIFO

// Clear RX_DR bit. (Write 1)
ReadRegister(REG_STATUS,1);
data2write = ( reg_data | 0x40); 
WriteRegister(REG_STATUS,data2write,1); 

CDC_Transmit_FS(&received_data,1); // Print the received data out.
```

}

When I disable while loop in the code, I continuously read 0x0E.

Edit: My new problem is related to Flush command.
I want to flush RX FIFO when a data arrives. I keep reading registers while transmitter is sending data and I can observe that a new data arrives RX FIFO which means RX_DR bit is set and RX_FIFO status is changed. Then I turn the tx off and execute FLUSH_RX command on the rx side, can not flush fifo. The registers still say that there is data in RX FIFO.

void Flush_RX()

{

```
csn_low();

HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)COMD_FLUSH_RX, 1, 150);

while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
```

csn_high();

}

Any suggestion, help, guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two communication mode as mentioned in PDF **nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0_1** page no. 72,73,74.
please just go through it. I worked with stm32 micro-controller with external interrupt. The sequence of commands passed to NRF chip will be dependent on two modes as mentioned below:

1. one way communication( tx will transmit and rx will receive only)
2. both side communication((tx+rx) <----> (rx+tx))

In 1st mode, you have to enable auto-acknowledgement,

In 2nd, disable the auto-acknowledgement.

### Hereby writing some steps for 2nd mode,

### 1> For transmitter side while transmitting:

a)flush transmitter

b)clear the tx_ds flag

c)pass the command for writing the payload

d)fill the payload

e)prepare for transmission

f)check the status

g)clear the all flags(maxtx,rx_dr,tx_ds)

### 2>for Receiver side while receiving:

Note: Receiver should be in reception mode always. If interrupt is used then no need to check the status bit.

when interrupt arrives;

a) read the payload

b)check the status

c)clear RX_DR flag

d)flush RX_FIFO

e)again configure as a receiver.

*Try this one*

Thank you, all the best.

***hi**,

for one way communication you have to enable the auto-acknowledgment,
and better to flush the receiver fifo after reading one packet. whatever data Tx is transmitting just check it on serial port or in other method because if payload length doesn't match with predefined one in rx, then RX_DR interrupt on NRF chip will not occur, so you will not get data on rx side.
for the testing just enable one pipe, check whether data is received by rx.

> chip enable and SPI chip select plays vital role in reading from payload or writing a payload.

*

Comment: Thank for reply. I will use 1st method for now. And I have some questions about 1st method. For RX Mode, 

1. As far as I understand, for one way communication auto-ack should be disabled according to the datasheet.
2.As I said, I do not use interrupt pin. I check RX_DR bit and if it becomes high, I understand that a data arrives RX FIFO and I write 1 that bit to clear. Is this okay?
3.Do I have to do anything about MASK_RX_DR bit?
4.I set pipe number and then shall I do anything about address or it will automatically identify the address in the related register ?

Answer (score 0):

For the RX Mode problem I may help, but I have no idea about Flush operation.

On page 59 in datasheet of NRF24L01+, it says

The RX_DR IRQ is asserted by a new packet arrival event. The procedure for handling this interrups should be

1)Read payload

2)Clear RX_dR

3)Read FIFO_STATUS

4)If there are more available payloads in FIFO repeat step 1.

Could you please use IRQ pin and check whether an interrupt occurs or not. If so, go through these steps above.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes on my code. I am trying to make a unidirectional communication for now. So, one side is only RX and the other one is only TX. I am applying the steps described on p.59 in the datasheet.

```
void RX_Mode(){
        ChipEnable_high(); // receiver monitors for a data

        while( !(IRQ_Pin_Is_Low() && RXDR_Bit_Is_Set()) ); // Wait until IRQ occurs and RX_DR bit is set.

        ChipEnable_low(); // when the data arrives, bring CE low to read payload

        ReadPayload(); // read the payload

        ClearInterrupts(); // clear all interrupt bits

    // This while loop is to check FIFO_STATUS register, if there are more data in FIFO read them.
        while(check)
        {

            ReadRegister(REG_FIFO_STATUS,1); 

            if((reg_data & 0x01)==0x00) 
            {   
                ReadPayload();
                ClearInterrupts(); // clear all interrupt bits
            }
            else 
                check = false;              
        }       

        Flush_RX(); //Flush RX FIFO
        check = true;       }
```

The code to read payload is :

```
    void ReadPayload()
    {
    csn_low(); //CSN=0
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)COMD_R_RX_PAYLOAD, &received_data ,1, 1500); // READ RX FIFO
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY);
    CDC_Transmit_FS(&received_data,1); // print the received data out
    csn_high(); // CSN=1
     }
```

BUT; when I turn the tx device on, I read the value of STATUS register which is 0x42 (means that RX_DR bit is set) then I continuously read 0x02 (means RX_DR bit is cleaned a). The data I sent is 0x36.